# Is deep copy necessary for props arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started getting into React and JS, and am trying to learn how and when to copy. Props are immutable, but for some reason when assigning an array from props I get no issues. Also, I know copying arrays is shallow, but when I assign 1 array to two variables in the state 1 does not change the other. What am I missing?

Comment: "but for some reason when assigning an array from props I get no issues" what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`but when I assign 1 array to two variables in the state 1 does not change the other`

Creating two javascript variables from the same array doesn't make them tied together. For example:

```
this.state = { a: 'foo',
               b: 'foo2',
               c: 'foo3'
             }
console.log('This is b: '+this.state.b); // => 'This is b: foo2'
console.log('This is c: '+this.state.c); // => 'This is c: foo3'

this.setState({ b: 'bar' })
console.log('This is new b: '+b); // => 'This is new b: bar'
console.log('c doesnt change: '+c); // => 'c doesnt change: foo3'
```

Also, changing the value of `a` won't change the values of `b` and `c`. If you want to update the state of both `b` and `c` you will need to do so separately.

Comment: So are you saying state hard copies arrays?

Comment: Yes it does. Changing the array won't change the state unless you run `setState`.